# boost unit testing exceptions

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I am trying to perform boost unit tests on a Client Server N/W.

How would I test if an exception is thrown e.g. `boost::asio::error::Connection_refused` if the Server is not online?

I have looked through the documentation and I am still confused (boost, c++ newbie).

FYI I have run a `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE` which contains a constructor that sets ip address and port # and connects to the Server. When I run the `BOOST_AUTO_TEST` I get the expected exception if the Server is offline and no Errors are detected but I guess my question how do `BOOST_CHECK_THROW` or `BOOST_WARN_THROW` come into Play if I am able to conduct tests without them.

Comment: It is completely *not* clear what you want to achieve. As far as I understand your question, you have already managed to write a test case that successfully gets the expected exception when trying to conntect to an offline server. So what is your problem?

Comment: Thank you for your Response Arne. I have run my tests without using anything like BOOST_CHECK_THROW or BOOST_WARN_THROW and I was wondering if such things are necessary? What is their use if I can run tests, get the exception without any failures without using BOOST_CHECK_Throw, e.t.c.

Comment: Oh I can *guess* now what your code might look like (you try/catch "manually" and succeed when you caught the right exception, right?), but if you'd be so kind to provide it we can tell you what the advantages of the builtin boost macros are. I assume you don't have enough rep to edit the question yourself, so just give us a pastebin link to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and we'll edit it for you

Comment: @ArneMertz He doesn't need rep to edit his own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can only guess what your current code looks like, I'll just provide an exaple of how your testcase could look like with `BOOST_CHECK_THROW`:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(testMissingServer) {
  MyClient client;
  BOOST_CHECK_THROW(
    client.connect(someNonexistentServerIP, somePort), 
    boost::asio::error::Connection_refused
  );
}
```

Doing this manually would look something like this:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(testMissingServer) {
  MyClient client;
  try {
    client.connect(someNonexistentServerIP, somePort);
    BOOST_ERROR("client.connect(someNonexistentServerIP, somePort) did not throw anything. Expected a boost::asio::error::Connection_refused");
  } catch(boost::asio::error::Connection_refused const&) {
    //ok, this is the expected case
  } catch(...) {
    BOOST_ERROR("client.connect(someNonexistentServerIP, somePort) did throw an unkown exception, but expected a boost::asio::error::Connection_refused");
  }
```

}

You see this is much more tedious since you have to check for wrong exceptinos and no exceptions at all separately. `BOOST_CHECK_THROW` does not only provide a more terse and more readable test case, it also produces meaningful failure messages if the exception you expect is not thrown.

Comment: Thanks Arne for explaining